# Мониторинг активности кливиатуры и мыши на C++

Tags: c++, winapi

При работе приложения нужно постоянно в параллельном потоке проверять активен ли пользователь:

1. был ли инпут с клавиатуры (любая клавиша)
2. двигается ли мышь
3. был ли инпут с мыши (кнопки, колесо)

Какими функциями это всё можно отловить?

Спасибо за быстрый ответ! Вот такой поток получился, может кому пригодится (`cout`-ы просто для проверки):

```
DWORD __stdcall CheckActivities(LPVOID){
    unsigned int OperationStartTime, CheckActivityInterval = 10000;
    LASTINPUTINFO LIF;
    LIF.cbSize = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);
    while(AllowOperations){
        OperationStartTime = GetTickCount();
        if (GetLastInputInfo(&LIF)){
            cout << LIF.dwTime << " / " << OperationStartTime << endl;
            if (OperationStartTime - LIF.dwTime > CheckActivityInterval){
                UserIsActive = false;
                cout << "User is inactive!\n";
            }
            else{UserIsActive = true;}
            while(OperationStartTime + CheckActivityInterval > GetTickCount()){
                if (!AllowOperations){break;}
                Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        else{
            cout << "Can't get last input info! ERROR: " << GetLastError() << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для клавиатуры - GetLastInputInfo(), для мыши - посмотрите в сторону GetMouseMovePointsEx()

Comment: Спасибо! Не знал про GetLastInputInfo.

Comment: PS: оказалось достаточно одной лишь GetLastInputInfo() - покрывает и мышь и клавиатуру